# Store object in ASP.Net vNext Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making a simple application using vNext that consumes `HttpContext.Session` object. It seems like the Session class only supports methods to set values of `int`, `string` and `byte[]` in the session. My question is: how can I store an arbitrary object in the session? Or is there a better alternative than doing this, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Methods you mentioned are implemented as extension methods over basic `ISessionCollection` interface (you can check in [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/SessionCollectionExtensions.cs)), which only deals with `byte[]`.

Anyway, to store objects, you would have to serialize them into `byte[]` or serialize them into string (e.g. with Json.Net) and store serialized value.